# Using a border to move a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm making a C# project with WPF and Visual Studio.

I'm stuck at trying to drag/move a `TextBox` around on my canvas in run-time.

I got the idea that, if you make a border thickness big enough, you could use the border for some sort of focus and then make an `EventHandler` for the border?

```
private Canvas DrawBox(ClassBox box)
{
    Canvas myCV = new Canvas();
    TextBox box1 = new TextBox();
    box1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    box1.BorderThickness = new System.Windows.Thickness(5);
    box1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    box1.MinWidth = 30;

    box1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    box1.AcceptsReturn = true;

    myCV.Children.Add(box1);
    Canvas.SetLeft(box1, box.Left);
    Canvas.SetRight(box1, box.Right);
    Canvas.SetTop(box1, box.Top);

    return myCV;

}
```

Comment: Check this: https://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/13/wpf-draggable-objects-and-simple-shape-connectors/

Comment: If you are trying to implement kind of graphic editor functionality on the canvas, I suggest that you can use adorner to fulfill your goal. The basic concept is that adding an adorner to your textbox when clicking, and then using the eventhandler of the adorner to move your textbox in canvas. Here is a link to the solution **[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1)**